# How to add pair to Users Ruby on Rails Class and sort by it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

**Controller:**
@users = User.all

**View:**

```
<%= @users %>
```

**Result** `[#<User id: 1, email: "a@a.a", location: "London">, #<User id: 2, email: "b@b.b", location: "Paris">]`

---

How I can add to User class one more pair without adding it to model?
something like:
**Controller:**

```
@users.each do |user| <br>
  @type = Types.find(:last, :conditions => ["user_id_addressedto = #{user.id}"])
  user << @type
end
@users.sort_by(:type)
```

---

at the end I want to see result as: 
**View:**

```
<%= @users %>
```

**Result:** `[#<User id: 2, email: "b@b.b", location: "Paris", type: "5">, #<User id: 1, email: "a@a.a", location: "London", type: "2">]`

Comment: Correct answer: add it to the model. Also correct answer: why wouldn't you want to add it to the model? [Note: "model" is not synonymous with "database"]

Comment: can you give an advice how to add it to the model ? (as you see I also need to interact with another model)  thank you for response!

Comment: If you have lots of users, it will be very inefficient to issue a separate Types query for each. I'd think about refactoring the model domain.

Comment: Why isn't `type` part of the model to begin with? If it's being persisted anyway, wouldn't a `has_one`/`belongs_to` (or whatever matches your needs) be more appropriate?

Comment: types are added consistently and only last type is required. they are stored in separate database table with relation columns `user_id_belongsto` `user_id_addressedto`  Not much users will be processed through this not more than 1-2 hundreds, cuz in controller not only `@users = Users.all`, but `@users = User.find(:all, :conditions => {:id => @repilents}).paginate(:page => params[:up], :per_page => 25)`

Comment: @antsav Please try and only use relevant tags for you questions. Take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions

Answer (score 0):

```
class User

  # ...

  def type
    return @type if @type
    @type = Types.find(:last, :conditions => ["user_id_addressedto = #{user.id}"])
  end
end
```

This way, it's in the model, but not in the database proper - and it's cached, so it's only queried the first time you need it. That is, only if you need it infrequently enough.

Note: if you are pulling 25 users and reading their `type`, it's 25 extra SQL calls. Maybe you'd rather make an association, or a `scope` column.

Comment: A shorter way to implement caching is: `@type ||= Type.find(...)`.

Comment: says: `undefined local variable or method `type' for #<#<Class:0x5604120>:0x55f6c20>`

Comment: Weird... I can't see where that error could be coming from. Which line is it reporting it for?